# I have a proportion DV with true 0 and 1. Which mixed modelling approach (in R) is most recommend?ed?

Tags: logistic, lme4-nlme, proportion, beta-regression, glmmtmb

Hope this isn't too much of a dumb question. I've been searching for a definitive answer, and now I've got choice paralysis.

I have a proportional DV (accuracy) with true 0 and 1 values averaged for each repeated measures trial during a specific 8-trial epoch. I do not have access to the original binary data per trial, 'nor do I have access to the total amount of trials to add as weights to a model.

Now, I've tried three approaches, to varying levels of success. My first approach was to logit transform the DV using boot::logit, and enter this into an lmer, as follows:

```
acc.mod1 <- lmer(log_rt ~ trial + (1 + trial | subject) +  (1 | cohort/subject), long_behav, REML=FALSE,control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun = 30000000)))
```

However, this produces an error, as my logit transformation created Inf values for the 0s and 1s.

Next, I tried to fit a generalised linear mixed effects model using the glmmTMB package, as follows:

```
acc.mod2 <- glmmTMB(accuracy ~ trial + (1 + trial | subject) + (1 | cohort/subject), data = long_behav, family = list(family = "binomial", link = "logit"))
```

However, I wonder whether using the binomial family is appropriate for a non-binary DV. When I change the family to 'beta' instead, which I believe is more appropriate for proportional data, it throws back the following error:

```
Error in (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  : gradient function must return a numeric vector of length 10
```

Finally, I even tried to fit a simpler beta regression model (with no random effects) using betareg:

```
acc.mod3 <- betareg::betareg(accuracy ~ trial, data = long_behav)
```

...but this gave me the following error:

```
Error in betareg::betareg(accuracy ~ trial, data = long_behav) : invalid dependent variable, all observations must be in (0, 1)
```

Thus, I've tried to incorporate what I've learned so far about the optimal treatments for proportional DVs, but it's all left me a bit unsure. I'm wondering if anyone more experienced with dealing with these models / DV-type could offer any insight to make my approach more robust.

Thanks.